# Error installing SQL Server 2000 on Windows Server 2008 (x64)

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, windows-7

Is there any way of installing Microsoft SQL Server 2000 on Windows Server 2008 (x64) server? I need to install but error throws "Microsoft Sql server 2000 does not compatible with current operating system." Currently i have SQL Server 2000 x86.

How can i install please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I tried that before, even if you change the settings to "Run with compatibly with OS" you will be prompted with several errors when the installation is completed.
The next closest version is MS SQL 2008. you can try the express pack first if you're concerned about compatibility issues.